# Jackrabbit 2.6 support for Lucene MMapDirectory

Tags: lucene, mmap, jackrabbit

I was wondering if Jackrabbit (2.6.0) can be setup to use Lucene's MMapDirectory. I could not find any manager class equivalent in jackrabbit-core as FSDirectoryManager/RAMDirectoryManager for Lucene's MMapDirectory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After reading a bit about Lucene's FSDirectory it seems that Lucene is going to use the best FSDirectory implementation (e.g. MMapDirectory) depending on the environment setup. The OS I'm deploying the jackrabbit is a 64-bit Linux and from Lucene version 3.3, MMapDirectory is the default implementation used so no actual configuration is required. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: This is correct if you are using a 64-bits JVM.